# skeleton css and bootstrap css in html file?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, skeleton-css-boilerplate

1.Are we able to use both bootstrap and skeleton together ?
2.Is there any order for same?

```
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css'>
<link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Problem : Skeleton css container is not displaying.

Comment: added the problem . skeleton container is not displaying.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it as there could be conflicting classes, no matter the order. Why would you want to use two different libraries anyway?

Comment: Why use skeleton + bootstrap? I see it totally unecessary.

Comment: Oh, I see now why this can happen, someone didn't plan so good the project, he starts developing with Skeleton, after some work he decide to implement Bootstrap because X but on my opinion now is too late, you will waste a lot of time replacing the conflicting classes, maybe is better start again with the desired framework.

Comment: am just trying bootstrap sidebar and skeleton animation together.I feel skeleton animation is good compared to bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can use both of them , but there is no reason to do so

2) the later you put it it gets higher "priority" , so in your case your personal css is override each one before him in case of a match.